# Fetching URL and Title from a sharepoint list and making the Title clickable

Tags: json, sharepoint

I am trying to print sharepoint list data on a page. My list contains only 'Title' and 'URL' columns. I am trying to fetch the title from list and then make the title clickable which will redirect me to its specific URL entry in the list column.

```html
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo= '';
    var listEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var urlolistitem = oListItem.get_item('URL').toString();
        listItemInfo+= 'Title: ' + '<a href=urlolistitem>' +oListItem.get_item('Title')+ "</a>'\n'";
    }
    //alert(urlolistitem.toString());
    document.getElementById('divListItems').innerHTML += listItemInfo.toString() + "<br />";
 
}
```

So now I am getting the title on my page which are clickable but when i click on it, it doesnt redirect me to the URL provided in the list. It openes

~site URL~/Pages/urlolistitem.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Just an update ---- The variable urlolistitem is fetching the URL perfectly. I have applied an alert for the last URL entry of the list at the end of the loop and it is giving me an alert having the last URL. I dont know why it is not binding the URL to the Title.

Answer (score 1):

It is working now. I am posting the script. Please look into it for your knowledge sreeraj.

```html
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo= '';
    var listEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
  var titleName=oListItem.get_item('Title');
        var urlolistitem = oListItem.get_item('URL').toString();
        listItemInfo+= 'Title: ' + '<a href="' +urlolistitem+ '" target="_blank">' +titleName+ "</a>'\n'";
    }
    //alert(urlolistitem.toString());
    var divListItems=document.getElementById('divListItems');
 divListItems.innerHTML += listItemInfo + "<br />";
 
}
```